# How to use custom html elements in styled-components?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

This works fine:

```
const Cool = styled.div`
  background: blue;
`
```

How do we do this:

```
const Sweet = styled('cool-sweet')`
  background: blue;
`
```

Comment: I saw [this](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/494) but doesn't really help much

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Sweet = styled(({ children, ...rest }) => (
  <cool-sweet {...rest}>{children}</cool-sweet>
))`
  background: blue;
`;
```

Comment: did you test this?

Answer (score 0):

```
const Cool = styled.div`
  background: blue;
`

const Sweet = styled(Cool)` \\override <Cool/>
  background: red;
`
```